# Configuring multiple mercurial repositories in Jenkins

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, hudson, build-automation, jenkins

We use about 30 repos to handle all of our software at our company.  Our code is mixed between C#, C++ and python.  We were originally going to use TeamCity for our CI server, and I found that extremely easy to setup with the way our repo system is laid out.  However, my manager has decided we should use Jenkins instead.

As I started to setup Jenkins, I discovered that it does not naturally have support for multiple repositories per a single job.  There is a plugin for this, but on the [wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) the maintainer of the plugin has admitted that it is more a proof-of-concept than a solid feature, so I'm hesitant to use it, though in the end, I may be forced to.

Should jobs be setup independent of each repo, where unit tests and builds can be run?  I can't see that as being a viable option, since our repositories depend on each other, unless I'm missing a configuration or a different plugin. Or can builds depend on each other to make something like this possible?

Our ultimate goal is to have Jenkins also handle our deployments to our dev staging area.  This proved to be easy to do in TeamCity, and I'm thinking it should be just as easy to do in Jenkins as well.  Can a job access repositories from other jobs?  I'm not sure if that's clear, but in team city, there were project variables that could allow you to choose any repo you've defined (i.e. `%FIRST_REPO%`, `%SECOND_REPO%`)

To summarize, is there a solid, clean way to handle multiple mercurial repositories in Jenkins?  Can other jobs depend on another and access another's repository?

I'm hoping someone with more CI experience than I have can help.  Perhaps a different CI server would work better for our setup, does anyone have experience with BuildBot?

---

I thought it might be beneficial to list how the repositories are laid out:

- app1.application
- app1.common
- app1.deploy
- app2.application
- app2.common
- app2.deploy
- platform.common
- platform.deploy

Where `app1` and `app2` will depend on some resources from `platform.common`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the answer was never figured out.  Our solution was switching to [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), which allowed us to do it fairly easily.  Build agents in team city can pull repositories into different directories, if you specify them to do so.  From there, the repo's could access dependencies from each other using relative pathing.

I hope this helps someone.  There may still be a way to do it in Jenkins, but we were not able to find a straight-forward way.

Answer (score 0):

As of the current version of Jenkins & the Mercurial plugin, it does not support pulling from multiple repos.

However, you can do this by having linked jobs, one job for each pull, and having them share a workspace.